# is there a way to hide button value without CSS?

Tags: html, css

Could someone please be so kind and tell me how I can hide the value of button without using CSS (I do not know how to use CSS)?

Thank you.

Comment: what do you want to hide? I don't understand.

Comment: look here for a css tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp

Comment: What do you mean by "Hide the value of a button", do you mean the value of the button when a Get or Post is made? Or when someone views the HTML you don't want the button's value visible?

Comment: Yeah, I don't vant the value to be visible on the page.

Comment: @Henkka: the whole button? or just the text of the button?

Comment: you *must* learn css basics if you are gonna stick to web-development

Comment: Just the text. Because the button has css styling, but the value of the button appears on top of that.

Comment: @naveen I don't intend to stick to web-development. I am just doing this for a course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great hack to removing text from nodes is using `text-indent`:

```
.button {
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This will hide the text in a screen-reader safe manner.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to do it with that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript

```
document.getElementById('yourButtonId').value = '';
```